# spring boot request.getRequestURL() cannot get https

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, ssl

My project is nginx+spring boot,
,spring boot is port 8080
,After I use nginx to forward, request.getRequestURL() can only get http but not https

```
public static String  getRootUrl(HttpServletRequest request){
        StringBuffer url = request.getRequestURL();
        String tempContextUrl = url.delete(url.length() - request.getRequestURI().length(), url.length()).append(request.getSession().getServletContext().getContextPath()).append("/").toString();
        return tempContextUrl;
    }
```

nginx is configured with https

```
    server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    xx.xxx.xx; 
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    server {
    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name xx.xxx.xxx; 

    keepalive_timeout 10m;
    ssl_certificate      cert.pem; # 
    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key; # 
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
            add_header Content-Security-Policy upgrade-insecure-requests;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

your nginx proxy to port 8080, this application is a integrated tomcat server, you not configure ssl in this tomcat , so, inside of the application, it is http, you can configure ssl in spring boot.